# button to add and remove class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, dom, addeventlistener

I have been trying to create two buttons where you can switch between dark mode for the website. it works for the first time but when I click on it second time it doesn't change, is there any way to achieve it

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  document.querySelector('.day').classList.remove('day');
  document.querySelector('.day').classList.add('dark');

});

document.querySelector('.btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  document.querySelector('.dark').classList.add('day');
  document.querySelector('.dark').classList.remove('dark');

});
```

```css
.dark {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative; 
  text-align:center;
}

.btn{
padding:15px 10px;
background:black;
color:white;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
font-weight:bold;
width: 100%;

}
.btn1{
padding:15px 10px;
background:red;
color:white;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
font-weight:bold;
width: 100%;

}
 .day{
width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative; 
  text-align:center;
}
.normal{
font-size: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative; 
  text-align:center;

}
```

```html
<button class="btn" >DarkMode</button>
<button class="btn1" >Normal Mode</button>

<div class="day dark normal">
This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

only with javascript.

any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: If you only want javascript why add jquery tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var day = document.querySelector('.day');
  day.classList.remove('day');
  day.classList.add('dark')

});
```

Example, the first time you run `document.querySelector('.day')` you remove the class day. and then you run `document.querySelector('.day')` again but this time there is no `day` class, so it can't find the element.

**Demo**

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var day = document.querySelector('.day');
  day.classList.remove('day');
  day.classList.add('dark')

});

document.querySelector('.btn1').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var dark = document.querySelector('.dark');
  dark.classList.remove('dark');
  dark.classList.add('day')

});
```

```css
.dark {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn1 {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}

.day {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.normal {
  font-size: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">DarkMode</button>
<button class="btn1">Normal Mode</button>

<div class="day dark normal">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: @Vijay No problem